# View Excel in WebBrowser control C#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, browser

I found a way to display excel file inside the WebBrowser control. I trying this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/Embedding_Excel.aspx) and this is my code.

```
private string _excelFileName="test.xls";
webBrowser1.Navigate(_excelFileName,false);
```

When I compiled the application message coming saying  **Your current security settings do not allow this file to be downloaded**

Please help to solve this problem.

Thank You

Comment: Internet Explorer may cause that. Can you check IE permissions please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with Internet Explorer. You need to open up Internet Explorer settings and make sure your security settings are not on High.

Alternatively, in order to enable File downloads in IE8 High Security settings:

- Tools > Internet Options > Security
- Click "Custom Level"
- Scroll down to the "Downloads" section
- Make sure `File Download` is Enabled

Comment: @leo87: Which version of IE are you using?

Comment: @leo87: Take a look at this [discussion thread](http://www.techimo.com/forum/security-privacy-issues/146417-your-current-security-settings-do-not-allow-file-downloaded-4.html) which has a few other tips you could try.